# Word For A Feature That Is No More Striking, But Still Deeply Embedded

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't see how I could have phrased the question any better. What I'm looking for is a *single-word* for a *characteristic* and/or *feature* of something that had probably been a *striking feature* for the observer once, but isn't any more. However, it is still deeply embedded in it, as much as ever. It just isn't the *distinguishing feature* any more for one of several reasons.

So for example, the question of *ethics* and *morals* of Christianity were a hotbed for debate in the 15th and 16th centuries. A lot of its doctrine boiled down to the questions of *right and wrong*. Today, though it remains a salient feature, religion has come to mean so much more than *just* that. And while most people don't pay close heed to it, and often show blithe indifference to it, Christianity is still based on the very same notions.

What would such a feature, still there with the same intensity, but no more as distinctive, be called?

Comment: Are there any more nouns than you covered in your question? I think it's better to look for an adjective that can modify characteristic or feature.

Comment: @Rathony I did briefly look for words that could flex out to mean what I was looking for. I couldn't find any.

Comment: No wonder nobody is posting any comment. It's not easy.

Comment: Just because you can think up a description doesn't mean there will be a single word it applies to. What's a single word for a left-handed nun who eats pickled herring before chanting vespers at a Lithuanian convent?

Comment: @Robusto Sure! I do understand that. Let them have a go at it, doesn't kill anybody.

Comment: What immediately came to mind for me was "windowing on computer screens." This was quite amazing technology at one point but it has become ***commonplace*** now.

Comment: @Jim Must have seemed groundbreaking at the time.

Comment: @Robusto _Grandma_, obviously. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the adjective "integral" in its meaning of [essential to completeness](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/integral).

Comment: A *defining*-- not distinguishing-- feature.

Answer (score 0):

Generic, cardinal, essential, fundamental, and principal, are just a few that come to mind.  If I had to select one for your example, I would probably use "Cardinal." Something that is Cardinal is that upon which all else pivots, but not necessarily the focus.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest **gain**.

gain: something wanted or valued that is gotten: something that is helpful: advantage or benefit ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gain))

*To appreciate the [moral gains](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ESTjQYS_8hMC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=%22moral+gains%22&source=bl&ots=PC39TprXfk&sig=yeeUq6LkIsF_mFAfTiv1t0dnALg&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAjgKahUKEwil6ti63avIAhXJsxQKHUJwB0A#v=onepage&q=%22moral%20gains%22&f=false) to humanity from desisting from exploitation, we need to take the longer view*.

If it's an adjective you're looking for, consider **established**.

established:

1. brought about or set up or accepted; especially long established.
2. settled securely or unconditionally.

([thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/established))

Answer (score 0):

The concepts you are discussing sound *foundational*.  *Merriam-Webster* defines *[foundation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foundational)* as

> a basis (as a tenet, principle, or axiom) upon which something stands or is supported:
>
> *the foundations of geometry*
>
> *the rumor is without foundation in fact*

Similarly *[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/foundation#foundation)*

> An underlying basis or principle for something:
>
> *this idea is the foundation of all modern economics*
>
> *without stability, the country will not be able hold the elections that will lay the foundation for a peaceful and democratic future*

Like the foundations under buildings, later construction may be the focus of attention, albeit still relying on the base.

Comment: However, it does not address the OPs question, since it applies whether or not the foundations were controversial when first applied.

Answer (score 0):

You could describe such a feature as being *[overlooked](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overlook)*. I don't think I need to cite this but I went ahead and linked to the definition anyway just in case.

I realize there are some issues with the word- it doesn't necessarily mean that there was something that there was something that was once meaningful about it.

I'm going to keep looking though as I feel there may be a better word or even a couple of words.

Interesting though, this reminds me a lot of *semantic satiation* where a word loses it's meaning from being repeated too much. Perhaps that may be a good starting point for finding a similar word that suits your definition.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **artefact**, **holdover**, **hangover** or **throwback** to describe something that was once intentionally created and still remains.

> ***artefact*** *noun* something made or given shape by man, such as a tool or a work of art, esp an object of archaeological interest

(Collin's Dictionary)

> ***holdover*** *noun* someone or something that remains or is kept from an earlier time

(Merriam Webster)

> ***hangover*** *noun* something (as a surviving custom) that remains from what is past

(Merriam Webster)

> ***throwback*** *noun* one that is suggestive of or suited to an earlier time or style. *his manners were a throwback to a more polite era.

(Merriam Webster)

You could add an adjective to emphasis the foundational nature of it.

> The protestant work ethic which values hard work and selflessness over the self, is a **cultural artifact** that persists from Europe's roots in Christianity.
>
> The protestant work ethic which values hard work and selflessness over the self, is a **foundational hangover** from Europe's Christian roots.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *inherent*, which denotes that a characteristic exists as an essential constituent or characteristic, or is intrinsic in some way but could be, perhaps, taken for granted.

*Foundational* characteristics, too, are sometimes taken for granted because they are built upon, much like an edifice which becomes the center of attention, although it could not exist without its foundation; the foundation makes the superstructure possible.

*Assumptions* are often unstated but foundational. They are like enthymemes, or incomplete syllogisms, containing unexpressed truths considered to be self-evident:

> We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable rights, among which are life, liberty, and the pursuit of happiness. [from the United States Declaration of Independence]

I could go on, but I think I'll stop here.